# Order placed event

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, payment-methods

I use `sales_order_save_commit_after` for same change to shipment and after this i save new subtotal and grand total, it's worked very well for COD but when i wanna use to another online **payment** the grand total that send to bank is last amount.

For example if the last amount is `500$` and new amount after my change is `800$` , `500$` sent to bank.

After many debug i found `sales_order_save_commit_after` observer run after payment.

My **question** is :  which order place event was fire before payment and is more like `sales_order_save_commit_after` event ?

Answer (score 1):

`sales_order_save_commit_after` runs after the order has been fully processed and saved to the database. If you are altering the order data, you want to do that *before* data has been saved. Moreover, if you are altering amounts, you want to do it before *placement* has occurred. Placement (`$order->place()`) is when payment is processed.

Try this event: `sales_order_place_before`

You can find it in [`\Magento\Sales\Model\Order`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4ee3bb36ab41a02618698e6b97e7c71f955bfb98/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1131).

If that won't work for your case, you'll need to give more details as to why.

Answer (score 0):

for each action's controller Magento 2 have one event . i use payment action for fixed my bug and it worked very well .
Of course i know it is not good solution but it fixed my problem.